# Move Files to Folders with same name

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd

I have 1000 files with the suffix `-PRO1` and `-PPR2` (1000 each) so I have 1000 folders with the same names but without the suffix...

For example I have a folder called `Abstract_Colorful` and I have the files `Abstract_Colorful-PRO1` and `Abstract_Colorful-PPR2` and so on...

I want to make a batch to be able to move all files automatically, I have this code (from another post)

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Folders\"
for %%a in (*) do (
  set fldr=%%~na
  set fldr=!fldr:~0,4!
  md "!fldr!"
  move "%%a" "!fldr!"
)
popd
pause
exit
```

but what it does is that if the file has more than 4 characters it creates a folder with the first 4 chars... What I want to do is that the batch recognizes the filename and stops at the `-` and moves to the folder...

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Folders"
rem Process all files in this folder separating the names at "-"
for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B *.*') do (
   rem At this point %%a have the name before the "-" and %%b the rest after "-"
   rem Create the folder, if not exists
   if not exist "%%a" md "%%a"
   rem Move the file there
   move "%%a-%%b" "%%a"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this:

- use the search bar in the Windows gui to view all files with the specific suffix (ie. -PRO1)
- select all in the GUI
- use the Move option in the window menu to create your new folder in the right directory and move all selected files into it