# Moving PDF files to folders with the same name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-moving

I have roughly 1700 PDF files that need to be moved to folders with the same name.

The PDF files are named as such:

> ```
> ABC12345
> BCD23456
> ```

And there are corresponding folders named as such:

> ```
> ABC-12345
> BCD-23456
> ```

Is there a way to move these files into their corresponding folders via the command prompt?

Comment: If you have more knowledge in C#, then do it in C#. Or Java. Or Python. Or ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move Files to Folders with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470322/move-files-to-folders-with-same-name)

Comment: Do the folders already exist? You say "folders with the same name" but the example shows the folders have hyphens in?